# Programatically add view behind status bar - swift

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I am having a problem showing the `StatusBar` in my `UITableViewController` because it does not have a background. So I want to be able to do that programatically. I have seen this in apps like `Facebook` and Youtube. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Make your question clear. What do you want to ask?

Comment: How to programatically add a view behind the status bar?

Comment: DO you mean to set different color for status bar and navigation bar. Ex : navigation bar color is grey and status bar color red. Or want to display Navigation bar and status bar as same color like Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a view behind status bar, you can use below code which is written for **Swift 3**

You need to create an extension for it and you can use this in any view controller where it is required.

```
let SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

extension UIViewController {
    func addStatusBarBackgroundView(viewController: UIViewController) -> Void {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size:CGSize(width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height:20))
        let view : UIView = UIView.init(frame: rect)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1) //Replace value with your required background color
        viewController.view?.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

and simply call this by writing one line in your view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addStatusBarBackgroundView(viewController: self)
    //Your extra code
}
```

Happy Coding..!!

Comment: That is what I am looking for, the problem however is that the background does not keep it's place behind the status bar when scrolling. I need it to do that :-)

Comment: @FeReTu Please post the code to understand the issue exactly. Also, Have you assigned the view controller class with sub-class as scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

To let your UINavigationBar stretch behind you status bar, you can implement the function position(for:) on the navigation bar's delegate.

## Swift3 Example

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBar.delegate = self
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
    func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
        return .topAttached
    }
}
```

Comment: it will produce error - can't add delegate to navigationBar